# Angular Lazy loading with multiple child routes

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

This is something I really shouldn't be stuck on, but I've not really used lazy loading beyond a single route per module.

I have a lazy loaded module like so:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
...other routes...
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
...other routes...            
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled', preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules });
```

Which points to a module which has child routes:

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin],
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            meta: [{ name: 'description', content: 'Administration home screen. From here you have access to the configurable parts of the site.' }]
        },
    children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
            { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
            { path: 'albums', component: AlbumComponent, data: { title: 'Album Management' } },
            { path: 'reviews-admin', component: ReviewAdminComponent, data: { title: 'Reviews' } },
            { path: 'users-admin', component: AlbumComponent, data: { title: 'Users' } },
            { path: 'roles-admin', component: RolesManagmentComponent, data: { title: 'Roles' } },
            { path: 'events-admin', component: EventsManagementComponent, data: { title: 'Events' } },
            { path: 'slider-management', component: SliderManagementComponent, data: { title: 'Slides' } },
            { path: 'galleries', component: GalleryComponent, data: { title: 'Galleries' } },
            { path: 'images', component: ImageFileComponent, data: { title: 'Images' } },
            { path: 'tags', component: TagsComponent, data: { title: 'Tags' } },
            { path: 'about-page', component: AboutPageComponent, data: { title: 'About Page' } },
            { path: 'faq-management', component: FaqManagementComponent, data: { title: 'FAQ Management' } },
            { path: 'blog-management', component: BlogManagementComponent, data: { title: 'Manage Blog Posts' } },
            { path: 'card-management', component: CardManagementComponent, data: { title: 'Manage front page cards' } }
        ]
    }
]);
```

Problem is that I can't get to the child routes e.g. dashboard/settings

This module was a regular module and worked ok, but I am using server side rendering and had a few 3rd party components that use window which lead me to disable SSR for any route containing "dashboard".

So my question is, how do I have children on a lazy loaded route?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I tried declaring each path as a lazy module withing the dashboard module, but when I do that I get the error that the component isn't part of an NgModule which is obviously wrong, because it is, so I am missing something.  If I add the lazy child component to dashboard declarations I'm told its declared in 2 modules, if I remove it from one I'm told it's in none.... Pulling my hair out now XD

Comment: Are you also importing the Routes into your DashboardModule? imports: [... , RouterModule.forChild(routing),...]

Comment: Yes, I export the "routing" class as RouterModule.forChild. and then import it in the dashboard module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out you can't use pathMatch: 'full' on the root, routes...

```
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent, pathMatch:'full', canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin],
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            meta: [{ name: 'description', content: 'Administration home screen. From here you have access to the configurable parts of the site.' }]
    },
    children: [

      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
      { path: 'about-page', component: AboutPageComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuardAdmin] },
    ],
  },
```

became...

```
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardAdmin],
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            meta: [{ name: 'description', content: 'Administration home screen. From here you have access to the configurable parts of the site.' }]
    },
    children: [

      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Dashboard' } },
      { path: 'about-page', component: AboutPageComponent, canActivateChild: [AuthGuardAdmin] },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: This is quite long after you solved the issue, but do you understand why this is the case? This isn't clear to me, and your solution seems like it will help me understand some underlying structure that I haven't been able to grasp just yet with angular.